# Paypal express checkout error (10445:This transaction cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later)in php

Tags: php, paypal

In my site, Paypal express checkout was working correctly in sandbox mode.
Today i changed it to live,then while i trying to make payment , iam getting an error response .

**error message = This transaction cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later.
error code =10445**

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013%2d08%2d18T01%3a10%3a34Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 2bd700a8eea48
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 76%2e0
    [BUILD] => 7319395
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10445
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%20at%20this%20time%2e%20Please%20try%20again%20later%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%20at%20this%20time%2e%20Please%20try%20again%20later%2e
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

I searched it about paypal.And in paypal , description about this error is

`"Inform the customer an error occurred and to retry the transaction. Offer the customer a quick link to restart the Express Checkout flow and redirect the customer back to PayPal."`

Don't getting any idea.

Now my site will get ,if and only if VPN is connected.Is it a problem for live payments?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you added and verified a bank account to your PayPal account?  Have you added and confirmed a credit card?  Does the error happen when you call SetExpressCheckout or DoExpressCheckoutPayment?

Comment: its happening when i do  DoExpressCheckout Payment.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, thanks for the reply .  My paypal Merchant account is linked  with  bank account.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, do u have any idea?.It is little urgent.We had raised a ticket in https://www.paypal.com/mts  , as per paypal error code description, but not get any response yet

Comment: If you want to provide a sample of your API calls I'll see if I can spot a problem.

Comment: I took the paypal class and reference code from http://www.saaraan.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php#comments

Comment: @AndrewAngell, i will try to come on your time today.Expecting your help

Comment: @AndrewAngell, any idea?

Comment: It looks like something you're going to need to contact MTS about.  You can reach them at www.paypal.com/mts.  Unfortunately, their response time isn't very fast.  You might also want to try calling.  If you log in to your PayPal account and go to Contact Us, then by Phone, you should see a direct number for tech support.  Call that line and they usually pick right up and can help you with that sort of thing.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, thanks for the response.We had already raised  a ticket  to MTS.But they didn't responded yet.Accordig to our code the integration part is ok, right?
Do we need any extra settings  for Express chekout in Merchent account?

Comment: @AndrewAngell, could you please give your email id  (linto.davis@calpinetech.com)

Comment: @AndrewAngell .,I didn't get any email

Comment: my client has opened a ticket in paypal support.Now i getting other error response

Error code:10007
Message:Permission denied
You do not have permissions to make this API call
Iam getting this error while i call  DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Comment: That would generally only happen if you're trying to make the call using your credentials, but on behalf of a 3rd party.  Are you passing the SUBJECT parameter in your API request along with the username, password, and signature?

Comment: No, i don't passing any 'subject' Parameter.I had a call to paypal customer care and they saying that indian customer can't pay through paypal's expresscheckout .Iam a indian  and iam trying to pay from my paypal account to us paypal account(ie Client's account). So this may be the reason?

Comment: @AndrewAngell, Also could you please send your email id to linto.davis@calpinetech.com.

Comment: @AndrewAngell.I have already enabled  the option PayPal -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences -> PayPal Account Optional  in my client's business account.But still i am not getting  an option to pay with credit/debit card without a paypal account.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530933/pay-with-my-credit-or-debit-card-option-is-not-comming-in-paypal-express-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was related to Paypal Merchant account.
That account was blocked by Paypal.
Now we created  new paypal account and its working fine.Nothing was related to code

Comment: How can I verify if my Paypal Merchant account is able to receive payments? I am having the same issue here. But I can't create another account.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and, after several hours reading docs, I,ve found that it was caused by the price used to test. We were using a too low price, what means that Paypal could not apply its taxes (without the taxes become higher than price itself).

So, I recommend you to find out what is the taxes to your region and choose a test price (or the final price) higher than taxes. It could solve that mess.

Comment: awesome. I had the same issue, trying to test with 0.01€ :-) thanks for sharing this